# Share Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows 7 Phone App on Visual Studio Express, and I have a partner I want to send my code to on a different computer.  Is there a good program to do this with, sending a Silverlight/XAML App to another computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to send it there, zip it up and email it or use a file copy (if it's on the same network)

If it's something you'll both be working on, you should be using source control.  (I prefer SVN, but there are other options.  You can usually get a hosted solution for a source control repository as well.

There's also CodePlex if you want to share with a bunch of people...
Really, there are so many options, this is just scratching the surface.

FTP could work
Hosting it on a web server could work...

Heck if you're on the same network, the XCOPY command can work..

Comment: Don't forget Bitbucket/TortoiseHg :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally that's called source control. "Sending" the code in any other way is just a bad idea.  There are loads of options from free to expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use dropbox sharing service. Register common account for you and for your friend, then move your solution under dropbox folder. It's all, now you and your friend always have a latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Just copy your project folder in My Documents / Visual Studio / Projects / ... to other computer. ZIP it first.

But be sure that the other computer must have same SDK & .NET Framework installed.

In addition, if you are are both developing the same project, consider use of version control software, such as GIT or SVN .